# x11 query top-level windows and map them to application which created it (making task bar)

Tags: java, python, linux, x11, dock

I want to recreate what DockBarX does but in Java.  So I need to be able to query the top level windows in X11 (I can do that already) find the PID (got that too : _NET_WM_PID) but then map that to the application that created the window.  I need to find which .desktop file (stored in /usr/share/applications) was launched that created the top-level window.
But the pid is not really helpfull, often the pid could be a child process of another process which makes things complicated.

How does DockBarX do it?  I'm trying to look thru source but my python knowledge is very limited.

Thanks.

Comment: found out that DockBarX uses libwnck (Window Navigator Construction Kit) to query this info https://developer.gnome.org/libwnck/stable/

Comment: overall it seems as though they use the title of the window to try and match it to .desktop files.  This seems very unreliable to me and I know will not work in all cases.  I was going to use _NET_WM_PID but it too is very unreliable and often not set by clients.

Comment: You cannot know for sure which .desktop file was used, this information is not remembered anywhere.